# How to create a vertical slider in octave/matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

#### Setup

The following command create a horizontal slider in octave/matlab filling the current window:

```
h= uicontrol ('style', 'slider', 'units','normalized', 'position',[0,0,1,1])
```

#### Background Information

With the function call `get(h)` you can display all properties of the slider. Some more relevant properties are listed here:

```
type = uicontrol
style = slider
max = 1
min = 0
value =  0.50000
sliderstep =[0.010000  0.100000]
position =[0  0  1  1]
units = normalized
horizontalalignment = center
verticalalignment = middle
```

#### Question

Is there any property to control the orientation of the slider? Or is there another way of creating a vertical slider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

I found the solution myself: The *slider orientation* is defined implicitly from the *aspect ratio* of the uicontrol. If it is initially *wider than high* it becomes a *horizontal slider*, if it is *higher than wide* it becomes a *vertical slider*.

To control the aspect ratio set the `'position'` property of the uicontrol to `[xpos ypos width height]`.

#### Example

The following command creates a vertical slider:

```
uicontrol('style','slider','units','normalized','position',[0,0,0.2,1.0]);
```

#### Notes

- If you change the aspect ratio after creation, the slider orientation
  stays as it is.
- The designers of matlab have not made a good choice by anticipating which slider orientation the user may want. A separate property for the orientation would be more flexible.

Comment: Have you tried this in Matlab or GNU Octave or both?

Comment: Octave only. I may remove the matlab tag, if no one counterchecks it in matlab.

Comment: Just for anyone interested, this does also work in MATLAB.